# How to insert existing arrays inside a 3D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a 3d array with the already existing arrays(Score, CourseRating, and SlopeRating). I would like to do so, so that I can match the Scores with their Ratings. If it is not possible, I was thinking I could maybe find the index of the score, and match it with the Course and Slope rating so that I can calculate the Handicap Index.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RoughDraft {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int count;
    int[] Scores;
    double[] SlopeRating;
    double[] CourseRating;

    System.out.print("\nHow many scores would you like to enter?: ");
    count = scnr.nextInt();

// ------ adds Scores, Course Rating and Slope Rating to Arrays ------ //

    
    Scores = new int[count];
    CourseRating = new double[count];
    SlopeRating = new double[count];

    if(count >= 5 && count <= 20) {
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.printf("\nEnter Score #%d: ", i + 1);
            if(scnr.hasNextInt()) {
                Scores[i] = scnr.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.printf("Enter Course Rating #%d: ", i + 1);
            if(scnr.hasNextDouble()) {
                CourseRating[i] = scnr.nextDouble();
            }
            System.out.printf("Enter Slope Rating #%d: ", i + 1);
            if(scnr.hasNextDouble()) {
                SlopeRating[i] = scnr.nextDouble();
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("Enter a minimum of 5 scores and a maximum of 20 scores.");
        main(args);
    }

    
    System.out.print("\nScores: " + Arrays.toString(Scores));
    System.out.print("\nCourse Ratings: " + Arrays.toString(CourseRating));
    System.out.print("\nSlope Rating: " + Arrays.toString(SlopeRating));
}
```

}

Comment: You could declare a class `Score` with the fields `score`, `courseRating`, `slopeRating` and use an array of `Score`s with the properties assigned individually nstead of using a 3d array.

Comment: @AliasCartellano sounds good thank you. Would it look like this?: `public class Score(int Score, int courseRating, int slopeRating){`

Comment: Change `Score` to `score` since you should use camelCase for variables in Java. I'm assuming you mean what the constructor should have in which case you don't put `class` in the constructor declaration.